# Wait for completion of AsyncTask and Loading of Map

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-maps-android-api-2, httpurlconnection

I am writing a code which takes input from one `AsyncTask(HttpUrlConnection)` to start another `AsyncTask(HttpUrlConnection)` which then uses the information to add markers to a **Google Map**.

The problem I am facing is that map has not loaded at the time when I try to add markers through `onPostExecute`. But when I try to use `onMapReady` the data has not yet been downloaded.

Is there a way where I can wait for both the data to load and the map to be ready before attempting to place markers?

Comment: Use a custom listener (interface) with a onFinished method and call that on postExecute. Since you need to do 2 asynks you'll need to do that twice (or just do both request in the same doInBackground)

Comment: You can set flags for each "step completion", or use the [Future](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for syncronicity

Comment: @Bonatti how can I do that (code please) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synce the question is very generic and provided no custom code, I will post a "generic solution":

```
boolean isStep1Done = false;
boolean isStep2Done = false;

private class ExampleOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return "Completed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        isStep1Done = true;
        continueLogic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Same thing for ExampleOperation 2, where it sets isStep2Done to true.
Then, if they are sequential, you can continue, if they are independant, on each you call `continueLogic()`, and the first step in this function, you check for all flags.

```
private void continueLogic(){
   if(isStep1Done && isStep2Done ){
      stuffs...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem use 2 booleans and set them to true when data load done and when map load done and in each of this async tasks add check if both true then launch adding markers )

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that it checks only once and if it is not true it skips the step altogether.

Comment: the thing is that you will check 2 times, and each async task, if task 1 will end first then you will fill data on second one, and if second will end first then you will fill all data in first one when it ends )

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following logic.

```js
public class MyAct extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private List<YourObj> mItems;
  
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    populateMap();
  }
  
  private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {
    ...
    protected void onPostExecute(List<YourObj> results) {
      mItems = results;
      populateMap();
    }
  }

  private void populateMap() {
    if (mMap != null && mItems != null) {
      for (YourObj o : mItems) {
        mMap.addMarker(...);
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```